# How can I modify my dataset (I have several columns with the same variable separated by month (wide format) and I want to structure it long)

Tags: r

I'm new to R and I need your help with the next problem.

I have the following dataset

| id | Country | City | Accrued_Jan | Accrued_Feb | Accrued_Mar | Paid_Jan | Paid_Feb | Paid_Mar |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | USA | NY | 110 | 110 | 130 | 100 | 100 | 110 |
| 02 | ITALY | ROME | 80 | 90 | 100 | 70 | 70 | 90 |
| 03 | FRANCE | PARIS | 70 | 80 | 90 | 70 | 70 | 90 |

And the result that I want is the next:

| id | Country | City | Month | Accrued | Paid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | USA | NY | Jan | 100 | 100 |
| 01 | USA | NY | Feb | 110 | 100 |
| 01 | USA | NY | Mar | 130 | 110 |
| 02 | ITALY | ROME | Jan | 80 | 70 |
| 02 | ITALY | ROME | Feb | 90 | 70 |
| 02 | ITALY | ROME | Mar | 100 | 90 |
| 03 | FRANCE | PARIS | Jan | 70 | 70 |
| 03 | FRANCE | PARIS | Feb | 80 | 70 |
| 03 | FRANCE | PARIS | Mar | 90 | 90 |

Any idea on how to do this? maybe with pivot.longer?

I would like to add a column that identifies the month and keep the name and values of the variables "Accrued" and "Paid" in separate columns

Comment: There's an example in this vignette that shows how to do it: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html

Comment: But otherwise, it would be easier to help by providing your data in copy/paste form, as opposed to an image.

Comment: @Martin your data is better shared in a useable format like `df <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~id, ~Country, ~City, ~Accrued_Jan, ~Accrued_Feb, ~Accrued_Mar, ~Paid_Jan, ~Paid_Feb, ~Paid_Mar,
  1, "USA", "NY", 100, 110, 130, 100, 100, 110,
  2, "Italy", "Rome", 80, 90, 100, 70, 70, 90,
  3, "France", "Paris", 70, 80, 90, 70, 70, 90
)`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could follow a tidyverse approach and use a bunch of tidyverse expressions. One way that helps me visualise it is how I would do something like this in excel and take it forward from there. [Here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) is a link to learn about tidyverse.

First you will have to activate the library:

```
library(tidyverse)
```

And then the code would look something like this:

```
df <- df |> pivot_longer(-c(id,Country,City),
                         names_to = "type", 
                         values_to = "amount")

df <- df |> separate(col = c(type),sep = "_",into = c("status","Month"))


df <- df |> pivot_wider(id_cols = -c(status,amount),
                        names_from = status,
                        values_from = amount)
```

Hope this helps. Happy learning!

Comment: Alternately, you might combine the first two steps using the `names_sep` parameter, like `df %>%   pivot_longer(-(1:3), names_to = c("status", "Month"), names_sep = "_") %>%   pivot_wider(names_from = status, values_from = value)`

Comment: Avi and Jon, thank you very much, your solution solve my problem! perfect..

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` solution

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- dplyr::tribble(
  ~id, ~Country, ~City, ~Accrued_Jan, ~Accrued_Feb, ~Accrued_Mar, ~Paid_Jan, ~Paid_Feb, ~Paid_Mar,
  1, "USA", "NY", 100, 110, 130, 100, 100, 110,
  2, "Italy", "Rome", 80, 90, 100, 70, 70, 90,
  3, "France", "Paris", 70, 80, 90, 70, 70, 90) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(
    cols = -c(id, Country, City),
    names_to = c("name", "month"),
    names_sep = "_",
    values_to = "value") %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
```

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that my database is much bigger, in the example it is only a part or extract of the database (it has thousands of rows and many more columns). Perhaps some idea on how to automate the script regardless the number of rows and columns that my base has?

Comment: That sounds like a different problem than what was posted here. If one of these answers was correct, please mark as answered and ask a more appropriate question for your problem.